# Extending YouTube API Quota with limited funds

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

With a simple java program, I send GET requests using [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) specifically [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list), in order to get the public metadata of a video and store it as .json files.

For my universities research, we have to do this with all available YouTube video IDs provided in the Youtube-8M Database.

Therefore, I would like to know if there is a way to extend the available quota for requests (*I already know about the billing option, but I am a student and my university is small*).

I have read the YouTube API terms, which states that only **one project per client** may be used to send such requests with the necessary API Key. 
If I understand it correctly, even my simple java code is such a client.

In some other Stack Overflow questions about extending ones daily quota with API Keys, some suggested creating multiple accounts or projects.

Is this a legal option or not? Or is there another possibility to get a higher quota for simple requests used in research like I do right now?

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) where you enabled the YouTube API. the second tab is called quota

[image]

Click the pencil next to which ever quota it is that you are blowing out.  A new window will pop up with a link called `apply for higher quota`.

Fill out the form to apply.  To my knowledge you do not have to pay for additional YouTube quota but it can take time to get approved. Make sure you comply with everything on the form.

I have never heard of the `one project per client term`.  Technically you can run your application using different API Keys it should work fine.  Technically there is nothing wrong with creating additional projects on Google Developer console.  You don't need to go as far as creating another Google account.