# Creating Multiple Google/YouTube Data API Keys

Tags: api, youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is it possible to create multiple API keys for the YouTube Data API?

The majority of Live YouTube Subscriber Counters use loads of different API keys for their counters (as can be seen in their JavaScript code).

The aim of doing so is to not exceed the daily quota limit of 1,000,000 and having to send requests every few seconds per page visited would mean that the limit would be reached very quickly.

How are they able to get away with this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43783163/8342742) to answer your question.

> Technically you can run your application using different API Keys it
>   should work fine. Technically there is nothing wrong with creating
>   additional projects on Google Developer console. You don't need to go
>   as far as creating another Google account.