# Does everyone need their own YouTube API v3 Key?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm working on an HTML file that allows people to find unanswered comments for their channel's videos. I'd like to make this available to the general public, or at least those willing to do a little work on their own. I don't plan on hosting it on a web site - just making the HTML page available, probably on GitHub. At least that's my thoughts right now.

(By the way, to avoid a discussion on authentication/authorization, it currently doesn't require authorization since I'm only accessing public comments, so it does indeed run in a browser, without being hosted.)

Since the web page uses the YouTube API v3, it requires an API key. Am I correct in assuming I don't want everyone using my API key? Does this mean that anyone who wants to use this HTML file needs their own API key?

Or am I thinking about this all wrong, and there's a better way to release this code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you request for comments, it costs one unit ([docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list)). Daily limit is 1,000,000 units. So if you exceed that, you might want to use multiple YouTube API keys. So technically no, your users don't need their own YouTube API keys, but personally I would make every user use their own API keys.

[Creating Multiple Google/YouTube Data API Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501961/creating-multiple-google-youtube-data-api-keys)