# What is the best practice to fetch all YouTube channels and their stats (daily)

Tags: node.js, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I want to fetch all channels from youtube and their daily stats.

As I researched this is the approach I have to follow:

1. Fetch all channels and store if I didn't store before  with this API:->

   [Search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)
   with this params: `type=channel, publishedAfter=yesterday's 00:00, publishedBefore=Today 00:00, maxResults 50, order=Date`. I will pass 24 hours range in `publishedAfter`, `publishedBefore`(e.g. 00:00 to nextDay 00:00) so that I can get the maximum number of results as youtube APIs have some bugs/limitations in paginations. They are giving maximum of 500 results per hit. I tried with a date of 2019 for `publishedBefore` and a date of 2005 for `publishedAfter` but I got only around 400 channels. That's why I am passing a small range of 24 hours.
2. After fetching all channels, I will fetch publicly available stats for that channel with this API. [Channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)

I will create a cron job that will run these steps every day at some time Maybe at 00:00.
And then I will calculate the current day's stats with some calculation with previous day's stats.

e.g.

`10th April views = 11 April 00:00 views - 10 April 00:00 Views`

My queries:

**Is there any other approach I can follow?**

**Is there any issue with the above approach?**

Answer (score 1):

#### It won't work, due to API restrictions.

In principal your idea is ok. I think it won't work due to certain restrictions.

If you believe [this website](https://www.tubics.com/blog/number-of-youtube-channels/) - YouTube has > 23M channels (as of December 2018).

YouTube has certain limitations on querying so, [from YouTube documentation:](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota)

> Projects that enable the YouTube Data API have a default quota
>   allocation of **10 thousand units per day**, an amount sufficient for the
>   overwhelming majority of our API users. Default quota, which is
>   subject to change, helps us optimize quota allocations and scale our
>   infrastructure in a way that is more meaningful to our API users. You
>   can see your quota usage on the Usage tab for the API in the Google
>   Developer's Console.

Assuming that you have this feature enabled, it looks like you have 10K units per day allocated to you and each of your search queries cost [100 units](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

That means you get to call the search API 100 times (exhausting your units before you call the channels API) - which with the max result flag (50 MAX), should yield you 5K results per day.

If this number is larger than people who are publishing everyday within that 24 hour timespan, you'll be fine and you might eventually have *some significant* data. But you **can't** have all the data through API calls. You'll be limited with the API calls.

If the # of published videos per day are larger than 5K (which I believe it should be well over that anyways) you'll be missing a lot of data.

#### It's pretty common, but there are better ways.

(This might not apply to YouTube, just a recommendation in general)

*We have something like what you've described running internally - periodically ingests a data source.* So yes, it's pretty standard across industry to have a cron job to do something like that. **The better way though ** which requires a different architecture, would be something like the webhooks. Basically, every time a stat changes you end up  notifying the interested parties that something has changed. See [Pub / Sub pattern for more info.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Now I have 2 questions. 
**1.** Pub/Sub: I know about pub/sub. But do youtube APIs provide that facility? 
**2.** Is it a good idea to request more quota allocation from google?

Comment: YouTube API's to my knowledge not provide that functionality - I gave that as a general example - should have called that out. You can request more quota allocation from Google, sure, but I don't think you'll be ever allowed to have the same data that they have. I'd be more focused on a subset of videos that you can manage to be honest, rather than going after everything. Everything is a very very very large set when you're talking on Google / YouTube scale

Comment: Edited my answer to clarify the Pub/Sub

Comment: I found this [Multiple accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782892/extending-youtube-api-quota-with-limited-funds) on SO. In which mentioned that we can use multiple API keys from multiple projects for same application. Isn't a good idea?   **I'd be more focused on a subset of videos**: In my application, anyone can see viewCount and subscribersCount of any channel from YT(per day). That's why I need all the channels.

Comment: This is most definitely not a good idea. If you're just trying to hack together a project which has no SLA / no reliability standards, then by all means you can try. Google / YouTube probably has their terms of service which specify how many accounts you can use (1) to access their services. What'll happen if your accounts get discovered and blocked because you're trying to exceed YouTube's allowed API limits? Your service would stop running!

Comment: Yes, I am also not sure about **mulitple projects/accounts** thing. I will look into this. 
Another way  I am working on to fetch channels daily as many as if the error(quota error) comes then hit tomorrow. I know this will take saveral days to fetch all.

Comment: @RahulSaini I'd appreciate the green tick if this has solved your problem :)

Comment: One important thing - you can't hit quota! If you hit it every day, your project will be disabled by google's algos.

Comment: @ArtemShevtsov That's not true. It's malicious intent that'll get you blocked, calling the APIs well within the limits is fine. Paying to get a higher limit so you can use the services is also fine. T&C generally would outline the scenarios which would get you in trouble.

Comment: @MaviDomates Please, read the TOS carefully: 15. Usage and Quotas. YouTube may set a quota on usage of any YouTube API Services at any time as applied to any specific YouTube API Services user or API Client, category of users or API Clients, or all users or API Clients. You and your API Client(s) will not, and will not attempt to, exceed or circumvent use or quota restrictions. YouTube may specify additional requirements relating to use or quotas including in the Developer Policies. https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service